Instead of running, my PWA says it requires Chrome
A PWA I wrote that worked well on my device (Samsung Galaxy s20 fe) now refuses to open and says " (the name of my app) requires the following app: Chrome" and has buttons for either "close" or "install" but when I tap install it goesto googleplay showing that Chrome is installed (no update option just open and uninstall).
I suspect this is somehow a result of permissions that were revoked due to long time of inactivity.
What can I do to fix it, and what can I do prevent this for happening to other users of my app?

Any News here? We‘re fancung the same problem. When I click install it works, but after reopening the app it asks again.

to be honest I am not sure how it was resolved. I think i uninstalled, updated chrome and re-installed the PWA. and it made the problem go away. this is not a good solution if this happens with real customers, luckily for me it was on a testing phase with a phone i had access to.

A friend of mine using my PWA reported this to me today. It seems that the only way he has managed to fix it (temporarily) is to restart his phone.

Same issue here. Suddenly both my PWA shortcuts are broken asking for exactly this. S22.
